# \ChoiceMenu multiple and simultaneously selection

Tags: pdf

I am trying to make a fillable PDF. Here is the example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,pdftex]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

%Encoding & language
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%Forms
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ pdftitle={Playing with Forms}, pdfpagemode=none }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\ChoiceMenu[combo, backgroundcolor=0.9 1 0.9, bordercolor=0 0.5 0,
borderwidth=1, charsize=11pt, color=0 0.5 0, checked, height=2mm,
name=aradiomenu, width=2mm, value={second} ]{radio-style:
}{first,second,third,fourth}

\end{document}
```

What I really wanted is not to choose just one item from the list excluding the others but to choose several items from the same list and that they are written in another place. Is that possible? I hope!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to make your file compilable, which is not the case at the moment.

Comment: Radio buttons allow only one value at a time, contrary to checkboxes

Comment: Do note that your form will face the following problem: in Adobe reader, people will be able to fill the form but will not be able to save the completed result (unless you enable this using a copy of Adobe Acrobat, for example). You can easily bypass this using a different PDF viewer, but I've not been able to find one which would display elements like checkboxes and radio buttons properly. (Text boxes seem to work fine, however, including multiline ones.)

Comment: Sorry. You are right. I wrote an extra "}". Now it compiles indeed.

Comment: And I changed "radio" for "combo"